# In ng starrating module in angular, dynamic value and read only does not work together

Tags: angular, rating

I'm using ng-starrating for rating option in my angular application and while I'm trying to display average rating for a particular item, by fetching the data from db and passing it to value filed, I'm no longer able to use read-only option. But if I give a value directly to the Value field and set read=only as true, it works without issues. But trying the same with dynamic data causes issue.

```
 <star-rating value="{{book.avRating}}" totalstars={{totalstar}} checkedcolor="gold" uncheckedcolor="gray" size="24px" readonly="true" ></star-rating>
```

[Star rating displayed if dynamic data is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtWqC.png)

Is there something I'm missing. I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.
I reported the bug here: https://github.com/riteshgandhi/ng-star-rating/issues/38

The only way to dynamically change the value is to set the element `star-rating` property to `readonly="false"`.